# WPF - behaviour of button in template

Tags: wpf, templates

I want to create button that always has the same behaviour (close window). Can I add this behaviour to a template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templates in WPF are used for layout and data.  I am assuming you are looking to attach your code-behind actions to the button template.  This won't be done through a template.  Instead, you probably want to look at building a custom control.  This way you can put your code-behind and your button together.

Here is an article on WPF templates and how they work:

http://wpf.2000things.com/tag/templates/

Here is a forum post on rolling your own button custom control:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a81ed36b-c9d1-4619-96e2-4025b919819c/

Finally, here is a good article from MSDN on all of these issues:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163421.aspx